# Accepted paper at conference but not presented

Tags: publications, research-process, review-articles

I have wrote a paper almost a year ago which it was accepted by a peer review in a conference. However, I never got to present it there due to excessive fees of the event. I want to cite this paper now, so my question is, can I treat this paper as unpublished work or is there a formal way to say accepted in the conference, or any other appropriate way? If it makes any difference i am using Harvard citation format. Side note, is it ok to upload it to my academia webpage and make a citation to there?

K.

Comment: What is the status of the copyright on the paper? Did you transfer it to the conference organization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us answer the question partwise:

> However, I never got to present it there due to excessive fees of the event.

This means that you never registered for your accepted paper. When you don't register for the paper, the conference committee consider the paper as withdrawn by the *Author(s)*. This ultimately means that the paper is not published anywhere (*neither online nor offprint*)

> want to cite this paper now...

**NO**, because the paper is not published anywhere (till now; considering this that you did nothing with paper after that conference)

> ...can I treat this paper as unpublished work ...

Yes. You can consider this as unpublished.

> ...or is there a formal way to say accepted in the conference, or any other appropriate way?

No. Even if you say, it does not make any sense to the listener; because, finally it never appeared in the conference. In no way, you can say the paper is published. But, historically, you can always say to your friends/peers that this paper was accepted in the *Conference in Historical Age, 20XX* (which does not make any sense at all)

> ...it makes any difference i am using Harvard citation format.

Citation does not have any role here; because, you can't cite the paper.

> Side note, is it ok to upload it to my academia webpage and make a citation to there?

No. Never upload the paper to professional networking sites such as Academia or Researchgate. In stead, what you can do is *you can submit this as a pre-print to arXiv* [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/) And then you can submit to any other venues.

**Suggestion:** You can directly submit the paper to some conferences or journals in your field.

Comment: Clear. It originated as part of my doctoral thesis, so considering the answer I think the best is to cite it as such and provide the link from the eprint version hosted in the research repository of my institute. On these grounds, is it better to cite the chapter or the page referring to the particular problem from within my thesis.

Comment: Yes. That you can do. It is actually nice if this is already been archived in your university repository. Good luck! @Kostas

Comment: I like this answer, 1+

Answer (score 4):

There are two possible cases here:

- (Default case) Your paper has not been included to the conference proceedings
  volume. In this case, your paper is unpublished. It might still be possible to cite it, e.g. by uploading it to arXiv and referencing it as an arXiv preprint, but this citation would have to leave out the name of the  conference.
- Despite your absence at the conference, the paper *has* been included
  to the conference proceedings volume. In this case, your paper counts
  as published and you can cite it.